# Do I need to replace my X-Box 360 DVD Rom drive?

Tags: xbox-360

When I put in a game, it just says reading then says open tray.  Simply, it never reads, just toggles between reading and open tray.   Do I need to replace the DVD rom drive or is this a software glitch that can be fixed via an upgrade?

Comment: Can you get any games to work? For example, did you buy a brand new game that hasn't been used yet and try? I only ask because most of the time the games have been used so much they almost get 'burned' where it has a hard time reading the disc (Call of Duty addicts will agree with me).

Comment: Related, perhaps: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253/is-there-any-way-to-fix-an-xbox-360-that-intermittently-wont-read-discs

Comment: Also note, you can't just "replace" the dvd drive.  There is a specific key unique to your Xbox and dvd drive that if you swap out the drive it won't work.  You need to rip the key off of the dvd drive and push it out to the new one, it's quite complicated but possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my original Xbox 360. I was able to fix this by opening up my Xbox and cleaning the optics. Usually, it is not the actual DVD drive. Note, that if you open your Xbox it voids an warranty and may permanently damage the system. I will link a few Youtube videos displaying  the process I followed. Usually if your Xbox is old (5 years plus) the optics have dust and other particles that inhibit the disc from reading properly.

[How to open Xbox](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaxIB6cXTYM)

Then just use a cotton swab to clean the optical parts of the drive.

Comment: Failing that, you might need to replace the laser assembly.  It isn't difficult, but you do need to desolder an anti-static bead.

Comment: OK, I bought a opening kit, removed the drive, cleaned the laser, still no good.  I'm prepared to buy another drive.  How do I know which one to buy so my already in process games won't be lost?  I literally have 2 more races on Forza 4 to be done with every race on the game and I don't want to start over!  I have the Phillips/BenQ VAD6038 drive.  Can I just buy another one of those and be good?

Comment: @michaelSmith The data storing Forza 4 is located on your hard drive, and not not related to the DVD drive at all. As long as your hard drive still works, you can access your saved game files from any other xbox