# Xbox 360 dosen't recognise discs

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360

I have an old white Xbox 360 and it has stopped recognizing discs.

Example: if I insert a disc in the Xbox it starts spinning the disc but after a couple of seconds, it stops and it says that I have to insert the disc when I have already done it, so my understanding is that its not recognizing that I have put the disc inside the Xbox and closed the disc compartment.

Can anyone tell me a solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you seen https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253/is-there-any-way-to-fix-an-xbox-360-that-intermittently-wont-read-discs ?

Comment: yes but the problem is different, beacuse not only it doesn't read the disc but it says the i didn't close the disc compartment

Comment: Xbox 360 consoles are "getting up there" in age at this point.  I remember my Xbox 360 (also the old White one you speak of) had the same issue, and that was _years_ ago at this point.  Unfortunately, the disc readers seem to slowly overtime stop working reliably.  I believe it is possible to replace the DVD drive, but you'd have to be willing to risk doing some repair yourself (or take it somewhere to get it fixed).

Comment: Ok i see, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that your laser is almost dead. My PS3 has been doing precisely the same - a few seconds of spinning disc and then stopping. Sometimes a couple of times, but with no result. Rarely was the disc read correctly.

I suggest you take your console to some service, but it will probably end with laser replacement.